# how to convert pandas series to tuple of index and value

Tags: python, pandas, series, iterable

I'm looking for an efficient way to convert a series to a tuple of its index with its values.

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

I want an array, list, series, some iterable:

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

Comment: That `pd.Series()` call actually makes `['a', 'b', 'c']` the index and `[1, 2, 3]` the data, not what you might expect. But your example suggests you want 1,2,3 first hence to be the index. `list(s.items())` gives `[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]`. So it seems to be what you need; maybe you just need to flip index and data in the declaration.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Well it seems simply `zip(s,s.index)` works too!

For Python-3.x, we need to wrap it with `list` -

```
list(zip(s,s.index))
```

To get a tuple of tuples, use `tuple()` : `tuple(zip(s,s.index))`.

Sample run -

```
In [8]: s
Out[8]: 
a    1
b    2
c    3
dtype: int64

In [9]: list(zip(s,s.index))
Out[9]: [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]

In [10]: tuple(zip(s,s.index))
Out[10]: ((1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'))
```

Comment: should be `list(zip(s,s.index))` otherwise you get a zip object in python3

Comment: @Seymour At the time of posting, I had access to Python-2, so missed out then. Edited to fix it for python3 scenario.

Answer (score 34):

Use [`s.items()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.items.html)

---

(EDIT: In pandas 1.5, there used to also be an [`s.iteritems()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html), just like in Python 2, with the distinction being `iteritems()` returned an iterator whereas `items()` returned a list. To get the output as a list rather than an iterator, you could do: `list(s.items())`)

Answer (score 9):

One possibility is to swap the order of the index elements and the values from `iteritems`:

```
res = [(val, idx) for idx, val in s.iteritems()]
```

EDIT: @Divakar's answer is faster by about a factor of 2. Building a series of random strings for testing:

```
N = 100000
str_len = 4
ints = range(N)
strs = [None]*N
for i in ints:
    strs[i] = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(str_len))
s = pd.Series(ints, strs)
```

Timings:

```
%timeit res = zip(s,s.index)
>>> 100 loops, best of 3: 14.8 ms per loop

%timeit res = [(val, idx) for idx, val in s.iteritems()]
>>> 10 loops, best of 3: 26.7 ms per loop
```